# remove 1st word in crystal report variables

Tags: crystal-reports

in my report some of data will show as below:

> MY22000940 / 020 /000

how can i make the words become

> 020 / 000

only if the 1st 2 character start with MY ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic:

```
local stringvar MyString := "MY22000940 / 020 /000";

If Left(MyString, 2) = "MY" Then
(
local numbervar slash_position := instr(MyString, "/");
Right(MyString, Len(MyString) - (slash_position + 1));
)
ELSE MyString;
```